# How to make standalone app using python on mac osx

Tags: macos, python, osx-mavericks

I am making an app in python 2.7 on osx 10.9 Used **py2app** to create .app.

`python setup.py py2app` is making **semi-standalone** app.

As **my.app/Contents/MacOS** there is shortcut to **/usr/bin/python**.

Now I tested this app on different system. It is not running due to corrupted system python.

So, how to make complete standalone app, so it should not depend upon system python. It should use app python or bundle python within app.

So, it should run on all machines independent of python health and version.

As following error is coming.

```
9/25/14 6:42:26.187 PM MYAPP[7814]:     from objc._bridgesupport import *
9/25/14 6:42:26.187 PM MYAPP[7814]:   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/_bridgesupport.py", line 9, in <module>
9/25/14 6:42:26.187 PM MYAPP[7814]:     import pkg_resources
9/25/14 6:42:26.187 PM MYAPP[7814]: ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
9/25/14 6:42:26.253 PM MYAPP[7814]: MYAPP Error
```

Comment: If a user has a crippled system Python, I'd assume it's their fault, no? Especially on OS X you can rely on a standard Python installation being available. Bundling it would probably make your app unnecessarily huge.

Comment: You can see the errors coming. So, want to make standalone